# Why does adding local IP and username in scp return public key error?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have two remote servers which have the same user and id keys. I can freely SSH to either of them from a local machine, or from one to the other. I `ssh`-ed to `100.100.100.1` and I tried to run:

```
scp -i ~/keyfile -r ognjen@100.100.100.1:/path/1/ ognjen@100.100.100.2:/path/2/
```

It returns the publickey error from the destination remote and a lost connection.

I accidentally realized that this works:

```
scp -i ~/keyfile -r /path/1/ ognjen@100.100.100.2:/path/2/
```

Why does the first fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Important note: The machine you call "local machine" is totally irrelevant. The real story begins when you're already on `100.100.100.1`. In the context of `scp` and in the context of this answer "local" is the machine where `scp` is invoked by you.

> Why does the first [command] fail?

You tried to copy between two (formally) remote hosts. `scp` recognizes `ognjen@100.100.100.1:/path/1/` as a non-local path. It doesn't matter `ognjen@100.100.100.1` points to the local machine. The tool doesn't (and shouldn't) check if an address that looks remote points to the local machine. Just by referring to the source as if it was remote, you made `scp` treat it as remote. Also the destination was remote.

Copying between two remote hosts can be done with or without the `-3` option:

> `-3`
> Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host. **Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.** […]

<sup>(emphasis mine, [source](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#3))</sup>

The bold fragment applies to your case (even if your `scp` doesn't support `-3`).

If you use `-v` with your first command

```
scp -v -i ~/keyfile -r ognjen@100.100.100.1:/path/1/ ognjen@100.100.100.2:/path/2/
```

you will see  `scp` connects from the local host to the source host ("incidentally" being the same host) using the key specified with `-i`. (Apparently the host is configured to accept this key, probably because the other server uses an identical key to connect.)

Then you will see another `scp` is invoked on the source host. The command is:

```
scp -v -r /path/1/ ognjen@100.100.100.2:/path/2/
```

`-v` and `-r` are there because they were in your local command. The source path is translated to a local path; the destination is unchanged. If this command run successfully, the data would be "copied directly between the two remote hosts".

Note there is no `-i`. Should `-i ~/keyfile` be there? Or rather `-i /home/cindy/keyfile` or so? (because the local `scp` got something like this after the local shell expanded the tilde).

No. In general a remote source host may be (and usually is) different than the local host. A path that is valid for the local host may point to anything or nothing on the remote host. If `scp` on the source host was invoked with `-i`, it would cause more problems than it could solve. It's a good thing `-i` does not propagate to the command invoked on the source host. But then the host connects to the destination using its default key or whatever its configuration tells it to use.

In your case it appears one needs the local `~/keyfile` to connect to the destination host. The source host holds the right file (because in this particular case the local and the source are the same machine), but the `scp` command that actually connects to the destination lacks `-i` (as it should in general) and therefore the key is not used.

Your second command used a local path as a source, only the destination was remote. In this case the key specified with `-i` was used to connect from the local host to the destination host, exactly as you planned. Therefore it worked.

Note if you configured the local machine to automatically use `~/keyfile` to connect to the other server (`IdentityFile` in `~/.ssh/config`), then the first command would work. The local host would unnecessarily connect to itself, only to tell itself to connect to the destination, but still it would work. The first connection would use `~/keyfile` because of `-i`, the second connection would use `~/keyfile` because of the configuration.

Comment: SSH agent forwarding could help, right? For example, if you don't want to leave your keyfile on 100.100.100.1 in order to connect to 100.100.100.2, while still being able to scp files between both servers directly.

Answer (score 2):

From scp manual, -3 option description:  Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter and selects batch mode for the second host, since scp cannot ask for passwords or passphrases for both hosts.

According to description first fails because 2 remote server will communicate directly (in real 100.100.100.1 server will communicate with 100.100.100.2 server via ssh) therefore you have to options:

1. Use -3 option.
2. Configure 2 remote servers to be able to authenticate with keyfile ssh key. If you can login from 100.100.100.1 to 100.100.100.2 server with ssh key your original command will work.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote " I can freely SSH to either of them from a local machine". I am aware of the -3 option but that is not an option for me for performance issues. But in light of your answer, why does my second command work?

Comment: My answer gives the same diagnosis, it was under construction when you posted. I decided to publish it anyway because it's less terse. It appears the OP is not convinced, maybe my answer will help then. +1 for you anyway, because you were first and on the right track.

Comment: @CindyAlmighty you have to SSH from one server to another one (because they will communicate directly not via local machine), not from local machine.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are correct, your answer did help, but I don't agree that this answer is "the same diagnosis". The -3 segment is confusing in both of your answers and drags away from the main point, and the second point is imprecise.